# Should one add class or id to a HTML document for better structure?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Usually we add `id` or `class` for CSS and Javascript selectors. When no selector is needed, should we just not put the `id` or `class`?

Example:

```
# HTML
<div class="name">John Smith</div>
<div class="email>jsmith@abc.com</div>

# CSS
.name { color: red }
```

You see that `.email` is not used. Should we keep that there, or remove it? What's the best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never add IDs or classes to your HTML unless there's a specific reason to their existence, like deep-linking to IDs, adding advanced styling or hooks for JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The class doesn't do anything, therefore it isn't needed. The browser reads it and it slows it (by almost nothing) but it still is useless.

The best practice, in my opinion, would be to not have a class where it's unneeded but instead write yourself a comment. If your code is long/you read it after a while, the comment may help you understand it.

```
<div>jsmith@abc.com</div> <!-- This is the user's email address -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont add Id's and classes to your HTML unless you are going to use it.

**NOTE:** Use ID's only for distinct elements. Use classes for common elements i.e., if you would like to apply style for common elements go for classes.

Answer (score 0):

There is almost no difference in ID ro class is you are talking about better structure.

They are selectors used to style the visual presentations of each element. If you read the wiki article about css from this site: You would have come to a point that the only difference is the importance or what we call **Selector Precedence** you can read about it here:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/info

The selectors are like this:

ID --> class --> element (DESC order from important)

Also, please try not to use them if you are not going to use them in CSS, I mean donot just use the ClassNames or IDs only to tell what this div is about like this:

```
<div class="email">username@example.com</div>
```

But use this:

```
<div>username@example.com</div>
```

Instead try to use the CSS only when you are going to style them, change the font-size font-family or other visual effects.